# MongoDB - transform array field to set

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have documents with a field containing an array of values which can be duplicated. I want to transform these documents with an extra field corresponding to **unique values** of this array. I tried aggregate + addToSet without success.

Data:

```
{..., "random_integers" : [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]},
{..., "random_integers" : [2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]},
{..., "random_integers" : [9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7]}
```

Expecting:

```
{
    ...
    "random_integers" : [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    "unique_integers" : [1, 2, 3],
},
{
    ...
    "random_integers" : [2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6],
    "unique_integers" : [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],

},
{
     ...
    "random_integers" : [9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7],
    "unique_integers" : [7, 8, 9],
}
```

Try with aggregate + addToSet():

```
# Query
db.getCollection().aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            unique_integers: {$addToSet: '$random_integers' }
        }
    }
])

# Results
{..., "unique_integers" : [[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]]},
{..., "unique_integers" : [[2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]]},
{..., "unique_integers" : [[9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7]]}
```

$addToSet add the whole list into a set, instead of each element of the array. I tried to combine $addToSet with $each but it is not recognize by mongo on a group:

```
# Query
db.getCollection().aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            unique_integers: {$addToSet: { $each: '$random_integers' }}
        }
    }
])

# Error
Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$each'",
    "code" : 168,
    "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
} : aggregate failed
```

Comment: You can just do the [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) on the _same_ array field to get the array with unique values (and no need for the $group).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
db.ints.aggregate( [
  { $project: { 
        random_integers: 1,
        unique_integers: { $setIntersection: [ "$random_integers", "$random_integers" ] },  
       _id: 0 
  } }
] )
```

Comment: This is working with `$setIntersection: "$random_integers"` too